# How to know when a file download is complete?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using url of a file assigning it to href of an anchor tag programatically and trigerring click event to start thye download of the file.
I would like to know, is there a way to know when the file download completes?

i am trying to achieve parallel download of files.